# How to change the front look of the website as it is showing without css?

Tags: css, luma-theme, custom-theme, parent-child-theme

I made the custom theme with the parent theme luma and now applied it as well but site lost its css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run below command once and check frontend

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: thaks for helping out. Admin panel options has stopped working but before applying custom theme  it was working

Comment: everything will be back just please run above all commands in ssh

Comment: Yeah I ran and got new exception

Comment: ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist in /var/www/demo/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24 Stack trace: #0

Comment: thanks for the consideration but it got resolved, I really am thankful to you for your quick solution. I would appreciate if you can share some study material or links for my magento 2 practice.

Comment: I am new to this I am upvoting it but its saying my feedback is taken I dont have any reputaion so its not visible to any one. I am following your solution, how to accept otherwise?

Comment: happy to help. thanx for accept answer

Comment: Could you please tell me how to work with the layouts? My front page is blank I need to design it.

Comment: you have to work as per your need.. please create cms_index_index.xml in module or theme do code as per your requirement

Comment: sure, would follow the same (y)

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:di:compile